# Can we write subquery in between SELECT and FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, subquery

i want to know, how to write subquery in between SELECT and FROM as

```
SELECT Col_Name,(Subquery) 
  From Table_Name 
 Where Some_condition
```

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
SELECT y.col_name,
       (SELECT x.column
          FROM TABLE x) AS your_subquery
  FROM TABLE y
 WHERE y.col = ?
```

...is a typical subquery in the `SELECT` clause.  Some call it a "subselect".  This:

```
SELECT y.col_name,
       (SELECT x.column
          FROM TABLE x
         WHERE x.id = y.id) AS your_subquery
  FROM TABLE y
 WHERE y.col = ?
```

...is a correlated subquery.  It's correlated because the subquery result references a table in the outer query (`y` in this case).

Effectively, just write whatever additional SELECT statement you want in the SELECT clause, but it has to be surrounded by brackets.

Comment: Just remember that your subquery can only contain 1 result set for each of the outer tables.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it, but you must use an alias for the subquery

```
SELECT Col_Name,(Subquery) as S
  From Table_Name 
 Where Some_condition
```